# Getting Win32_Service security descriptor using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am using VbScript for retrieving the securitydescriptor of a Win32_Service. I am using the following code:

```
 SE_DACL_PRESENT = &h4
 ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE = &h0
 ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE  = &h1

 strComputer = "."
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (Security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

 Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Service")

 For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objPrinter.Name 
 ' Get security descriptor for printer
  Return = objPrinter.GetSecurityDescriptor( objSD )
  If ( return <> 0 ) Then
  WScript.Echo "Could not get security descriptor: " & Return
  wscript.Quit Return
  End If
 ' Extract the security descriptor flags
  intControlFlags = objSD.ControlFlags
  If intControlFlags AND SE_DACL_PRESENT Then
 ' Get the ACE entries from security descriptor
   colACEs = objSD.DACL
  For Each objACE in colACEs
 ' Get all the trustees and determine which have access to printer
   WScript.Echo objACE.Trustee.Domain & "\" & objACE.Trustee.Name
   If objACE.AceType = ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE Then
    WScript.Echo vbTab & "User has access to printer"
   ElseIf objACE.AceType = ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE Then
    WScript.Echo vbTab & "User does not have access to the printer"
   End If
  Next
  Else
  WScript.Echo "No DACL found in security descriptor"
 End If
 Next
```

However, every time I run it I get the message saying the resulting code is -2147023582 something, rather than the error codes defined in
[the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390785%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Anyone got any ideas? I am using Windows 7 professional 64-bit.

The number is -2147023582. Could it be some sort of 64-bit issue? doesn't that look like a unsigned integer stored as a signed integer?

(PS: don't mind the variablenames... I ripped an example off of msdn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code -2147023582 (0x80070522) means "A required privilege is not held by the client." Most likely, the `Security` privilege in the WMI moniker is not enough, and you need to run your script as Administrator. (At least, your script works fine for me on 64-bit Vista when run as admin.)

Comment: Thanks. But should not that be return code 2 or 9 according to the manual (posted above)? The -2147023582 value is not defined in the table.

Comment: @invictus: Apparently, not necessarily. This is a generic Windows system error.

Comment: You were right. Do you know if its possible to enforce the vbscript to request Administrator privileges and trigger UAC?

Comment: @invictus: Looks like this is possible. Here're some links with more info: [Scripting Elevation on Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/01/scripting-elevation-on-vista.aspx), [VBScripts and UAC elevation](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/185/1/VBScripts-and-UAC-elevation.html), [VBScript UAC Prompting Kit](http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/vbscriptuackit).